# Add world street map to basemap

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am having problems with basemap - arcgisimage function. Sample code below

...

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

m = Basemap(
    llcrnrlat=40.361369, llcrnrlon=-80.0955278,
    urcrnrlat=40.501368, urcrnrlon=-79.865723,
    epsg = 2272
)
#m.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D'
, xpixels=7000, verbose=True)
m.arcgisimage(service='World_Physical_Map', xpixels=7000, ypixels=None, dpi=96,verbose=True)

#m.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels=7000, verbose=True)

plt.show()
```

...

when I run this the arcgisimage() function crashes in PIL with error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Machine Learning\Geospatial\pittsburgh_map.py", line 11, in <module>
    m.arcgisimage(service='World_Physical_Map', xpixels=7000, ypixels=None, dpi=96,verbose=True)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4263, in arcgisimage
    return self.imshow(imread(urlopen(basemap_url)),ax=ax,
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1490, in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 692, in _open
    cid, pos, length = self.png.read()
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 162, in read
    pos = self.fp.tell()
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

Comment: How did you install mpl_toolkits? Make sure you’re following Basemap installation instructions: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

Comment: thanks am running on windows 10 and there were issues installing. I think pip or conda finally worked. the link seems to refer to linux?

Comment: which method would you recommend? I have py 3.8.6 installed. Initially I had 3.9 but had to go to an earlier version to get libraries that were compatible. Everything else seems to work in basemap except for this arcgisimage() function

Comment: The link also gives info on the Windows binaries — that’s what I’d use to install. Edit: basemap is deprecated in favor of cartopy https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap

Comment: I used conda or pip with a .whl file - not quite sure since it was very hard to install. I thought those instructions were for linux? basemap seems to work except for the arcgisimage() function. does this need another library to work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, most probably you have installed it using conda. I deinstalled the basemap module and reinstalled it with pip. then everything worked normally

Comment: thanks - I tried this and then reinstalled used pip with the .whl file but still have the same issue. all other features of basemap work except for this. It shows that basemap 1.2.2 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the basemap installation instructions, then any issues you have with running basemap will probably remain unfixed as it is is deprecated in favor of cartopy https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.

Comment: this workaround worksimport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from PIL import Image
import urllib
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlon=-90,llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlon=-60,urcrnrlat=60, epsg="4326")

bm_url = f"http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer/export?bbox={m.llcrnrlon},{m.llcrnrlat},{m.urcrnrlon},{m.urcrnrlat}&bboxSR=4326&imageSR=4326&size=400,400&dpi=96&format=png32&transparent=true&f=image"

im = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(bm_url))

m.imshow(im, origin="upper")
plt.show()